# Use the same variable value in other feature in cucumber

Tags: java, selenium, cucumber-java

Following are my features and step definitions

```
@Regression
  Scenario: Validate workflow with research ticket having risk rating 3 and Complexity as No known difficulty (assign to other)
    When "Analyst" logs in to application
    Then "MISToolKit" page should appear
    Then User navigates to "ResearchTicketDashboard" page
    When A research ticket with risk rating 3 is created or selected
    #Then It should be displayed in Awaiting research tab
    Then I Assign that ticket to other analyst

  @Smoke
  Scenario: Validate if ticket having risk rating 3 and No known difficulty complexity is properly processed on other analyst login
    When "otheranalyst" logs in to application
    Then "MISToolKit" page should appear
    Then User navigates to "ResearchTicketDashboard" page
    Then Ticket assigned should be displayed in In research tab of that analyst
    When Set complexity as No known difficulty and clicked on commit
    Then It should be displayed in Awaiting Review tab
    credentials



String researchticketId;

@When("A research ticket with risk rating {int} is created or selected")
    public void a_research_ticket_with_risk_rating_is_created_or_selected(Integer int1) {
        rs.selectriskratingandresearchattribute();
        researchticketId=rs.getrefidlist().get(0).getAttribute("innerHTML");
        System.out.println(researchticketId);
        WaitActions.wait(3000);
    }

@Then("Ticket assigned should be displayed in In research tab of that analyst")
    public void ticket_assigned__should_be_displayed_in_in_research_tab_of_that_analyst() {
        rs.clickonInResearchtab();
        rs.waitforfivesec();
        rs.findresearchticketId(researchticketId);
        rs.waitforfivesec();
        Assert.assertEquals(researchticketId, rs.getrefidlist().get(0).getText());
```

As you can see the step in @Regression feature has a value stored in string researchticketID(step @When("A research ticket with risk rating {int} is created or selected")) and that I want to use in @Smoke feature whose step definition is as above (@Then("Ticket assigned should be displayed in In research tab of that analyst")). But in the @Smoke feature step definition, on line rs.findresearchticketId(researchticketId); the researchticketId value is passed as null as a result my tests are failing. The error been given is

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Keys to send should be a not null CharSequence
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.sendKeys(RemoteWebElement.java:97)
```

Please help me.

Comment: Dependency ordering between scenarios isn’t great - and usually unsupported. The Cucumber DI frameworks generally reset the context between scenarios.

Comment: You could hoik the common steps out to a Background.

Comment: My scenario needs that approach. I cannot put that step in Background. I need to launch new session twice which I cannot do in one feature hence this approach. Any workaround other than that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare variable `researchticketId` as `static`.

Refer https://www.javatpoint.com/static-keyword-in-java